# Breeze and Angular2

Tags: angular, breeze

I am developing a data service with Angular2. I want use Breeze to query data from a Breeze Controller, which is hosted on a ASP.NET MVC6 project. 
I had a look to Ward last solution Breeze with angular 2 http://plnkr.co/edit/QRPg7M?p=preview.

I have a service like BreezeHeroService, i have created q.ts as illustrated and imported in my data service.

However, i have compilation error in 
breeze.config.setQ(Q): "Cannot fine name breeze".

In my package.json i have the following dependencies

"dependencies": {

```
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
"bootstrap": "3.3.6",
"systemjs": "0.19.6",
"es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "0.6.12",
"jquery": "2.1.4",
"breeze-client": "1.5.7"
```

},

I have a gulp file with the following items copied to js folder under wwwroot:

```
'./node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.debug.js',

'./node_modules/breeze-client/build/adapters/breeze.bridge.angular.js'


In _Layout.cshtml i have following references:

src="~/js/breeze.debug.js"

src="~/js/breeze.bridge.angular.js"
```

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: Out of interest, do you recommend using BreezeJS with ng2? I have it working, however I have noticed there is not a lot of activity for it and I am considering scrapping it and writing data services the pure Angular2 way. I would love to hear from Ward or some other of the project sponsors if they personally still recommend using Breeze for Angular2 projects?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the latest bridge for Breeze Angular 2, you do not have to configure Q yourself. All the initial config is handed by injecting the bridge.

The following link got me started [Breeze Bridge Angular2](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.bridge.angular2/blob/master/README.md)

Don't forget to include a reference to datajs if you will use breezejs with an odata service.

Solutiuon:

Install breeze-client

```
npm install breeze-client --save
```

Install breeze-bridge-angular2

```
npm install breeze-bridge-angular2 --save
```

To use the bridge in your own application, the following steps are required.

Configure breeze-client and breeze-bridge-angular2 in systemjs.config.js.

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
  ...
  'breeze-client':              'node_modules/breeze-client',
  'breeze-bridge-angular2':     'node_modules/breeze-bridge-angular2'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
  ...
  'breeze-client':              { main: 'breeze.debug.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
  'breeze-bridge-angular2':     { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
};
```

Import HTTP_PROVIDERS and BreezeBridgeAngular2 and add them to the app component's providers list.

```
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { BreezeBridgeAngular2 } from 'breeze-bridge-angular2';
@Component({
  providers: [
    BreezeBridgeAngular2,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

One-time inject BreezeBridgeAngular2 and start using Breeze. The act of injecting the bridge causes the system to self-configure. The only requirement is that the bridge needs to be injected once before the first call to Breeze.

```
import { BreezeBridgeAngular2 } from 'breeze-bridge-angular2';

@Component({...
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(bridge: BreezeBridgeAngular2) {  } // configure once by injecting bridge - no need to use it here
}
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityManager, EntityQuery } from 'breeze-client';
import { Customer } from './entities';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private _em: EntityManager;

  constructor() {
    this._em = new EntityManager();
  }

  getAllCustomers(): Promise<Customer[]> {
    let query = EntityQuery.from('Customers').orderBy('companyName');

    return <Promise<Customer[]>><any> this._em.executeQuery(query)
    .then(res => res.results)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Notice that we are also importing breeze-client instead of loading it as a static script as you might have seen in other examples. Make sure you don't have an extra script tag in your index.html that attempts to statically load breeze.debug.js or similar.

Example index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I managed to get Angular2 RC4 working by following the above steps.

I am using an OData enpoint and added the following configuration to my data service (all the needed imports come from 'breeze-client'):

```
constructor() {
    // Tell Breeze we are using an OData service created by a C# WebApi2 + EF6 solution
    config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);
    this._em = new EntityManager('http://localhost:60062/odata');
    // Breeze doesn't know that EF will manage my entities Id's (SQL Identity columns), so we need to tell Breeze that the server will handle Id values)
    this._em.fetchMetadata((schema) => {
      console.log('schema', schema);
      var collectionPointType = this._em.metadataStore.getEntityType("CollectionPoint");
      (<any>collectionPointType).setProperties({ autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do I have to create my entity classes manually in typescript in order to get the line import { Customer } from './entities';
working?